# Python max value for generic type

Tags: python

If I’m writing e.g. a sort function that’s supposed to work on generic ordered types, is there a constant I can use that is guaranteed to always compare greater than any actual value? Something like math.inf, but not just for integers.

I want to do something like this:

```
def current_min(self):
    if self.is_empty():
         current_min = infinity
    else:
        current_min = self.min
   
def update(self, new):
    self.min = min(self.current_min(), new)
```

(Certainly there’s plenty of other ways to achieve something similar to the above, I’m just curious!)

Comment: You can make your own class that's larger than anything, `__gt__` just returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an existing way. A simple class can be done up though that always tests as greater than anything else:

```
class AlwaysGT:
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return True
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False
AGT = AlwaysGT()
```

Then:

```
>>> 1 > AGT
False
>>> AGT > 1
True
>>> object() > agt
False
>>> AGT > math.inf
True
```

I've never used this before beyond initial testing, but I don't know of any drawbacks to this method, beyond that it's non-standard. Of course this only works though if the only operators used are `>` and `<`. If you require more flexibility, the other answer would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

One of my libraries, [`python-ranges`](https://github.com/Superbird11/ranges), includes an infinity object that always compares as greater than anything, and also pretends to be `float('inf')` when its exact value is called for. In that project, `+Inf` and `-Inf` are used as the default endpoints for an infinite range, and are meant to be able to compare to dates, strings, and any other comparable object you could theoretically put in a range.

You can either import `Inf` from that project, or just copy [the source for the infinity object itself](https://github.com/Superbird11/ranges/blob/master/ranges/_helper.py#L18), which might be what you need:

```
class _InfiniteValue(Number):
    """
    A class representing positive or negative infinity, mainly as a stand-in for float's version
    of infinity, able to represent an infinite value for other types.
    """
    def __init__(self, negative=False):
        self.negative = negative
        self.floatvalue = float('-inf' if self.negative else 'inf')

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """ -infinity is always less """
        if isinstance(other, float):
            return self.floatvalue < other
        else:
            return self.negative and not self == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        """ +infinity is always more """
        if isinstance(other, float):
            return self.floatvalue > other
        else:
            return not self.negative and not self == other

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self < other or self == other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self > other or self == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ for consistency, infinity is equal to itself """
        if isinstance(other, float):
            return self.floatvalue == other
        elif isinstance(other, _InfiniteValue):
            return self.negative == other.negative
        else:
            return False

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.floatvalue + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + self.floatvalue

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.floatvalue - other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return other - self.floatvalue

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.floatvalue * other

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return other * self.floatvalue

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.floatvalue / other

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return other / self.floatvalue

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self.floatvalue // other

    def __rfloordiv__(self, other):
        return other // self.floatvalue

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self.floatvalue % other

    def __rmod__(self, other):
        return other % self.floatvalue

    def __divmod__(self, other):
        return divmod(self.floatvalue, other)

    def __rdivmod__(self, other):
        return divmod(other, self.floatvalue)

    def __neg__(self):
        return _InfiniteValue(negative=not self.negative)

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.floatvalue)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.floatvalue

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.floatvalue)

    def __repr__(self):
        """ pretend to be float infinity """
        return repr(self.floatvalue)

    def __hash__(self):
        """ pretend to be float infinity """
        return hash(self.floatvalue)


Inf = _InfiniteValue()
```

This may be over-engineered for the problem you're trying to solve, though.

Answer (score 0):

Be explicit about whether you haven't seen a value yet and what the smallest value is if you've seen at least one.

```
def current_min(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        current_min = None  # No current minimum
    else:
        current_min = self.min
   
def update(self, new):
    if self.current_min() is None:
        # This is the first value I've seen, so it is by definition
        # the smallest seen so far.
        self.min = new
    else:
        self.min = min(self.current_min(), new)
```